# Rotating curve 90 or 270 degrees suddenly flips object with curve modifier

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

Rotating the curve along the Y axis results in a linear rotation of the object itself. But that can be counteracted by counterrotating the object.
[image]

This is the curve rotated 45° along the Y axis.
[image]

This is the curve rotated 90° along the Y axis. The rotation is linear so it can be easily counteracted.
[image]

Rotating the curve along the Z axis by 45° doesn't rotate the object.[image]

Rotating past 85° along the Z axis however results in rotation of the object which turns upright at 90° (image) and past that it turns upside down which reverses when hitting 270°. The model itself (tank tracks) has to be able to rotate in all directions for animation purposes. Is this an improper way to animate tank tracks? What causes the issue and how can I fix it?
EDIT:
[image]

Here are my curve data settings

Comment: Could you show your curve's Object data tab? What you are using as Twisting option?

Comment: I use the default settings, twisting is "minimum"

Comment: Are you rotating both the curve and the arrayed object at the same time? Try switching *Twisting* to Z-Up